# conditional check in grails site mesh

Tags: grails, sitemesh

I have my gsp pages all applying the layout from main.gsp.  Main.gsp is using the bootstrap layout and a container to make the pages responsive.  In a few of the pages on my site I'm trying to use a liquid layout and don't want to have a container wrapping all of the content in each of the sub pages.

Is there a way to pass a variable or set something in a page that applies the layout of main.gsp, and have a conditional piece of code execute in the main layout?

Neither of these attempts below worked.  In one I'm setting a variable in the sub page, and in another attempt I'm passing in a variable in the model.  In both cases the container is being rendered in profile.gsp.

main.gsp:

```
<body>
<g:if test="${fluid != true}">
<div class="container">
</g:if>
...
```

profile.gsp:

```
<g:set var="fluid" value="true"/>

<g:applyLayout name="main" model="[fluid:'true']">
<html>
<head>
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You are Setting a String value to  var fluid in:

```
<g:set var="fluid" value="true"/>
```

In case `<g:if test="${fluid != true}">` it is checking a boolean not string comparison so  you need to define either a boolean or you need to check for sstring comparison.

To set boolean you can do  `<g:set var="fluid" value="${true}"/>` cause `"true"` will make it just a string with value true not a boolean true.

Answer (score 0):

in addtion to Sachin Vermas response, you can use two additional approaches:

1. not a clean solution, but it should work: in the layout, there is the params-map and the session available, so you could store your flag in one of those objects.
2. another solution would be to not only do a conditional check in your layout, but use a whole new layout:

   ```
   '<g:applyLayout name="${fluid?'fluid':'main'" >'
   ```

but as Sachin Verma already replyed, the `fluid` variable has to be of the right type. As I do understand, in your case you even wouldn't have to dynamicalle switch between two layouts, but you could just use `

```
<g:applyLayout name="fluid" >`
```

for your fluid pages and `

```
<g:applyLayout name="main" >`
```

otherwise. This would make your code even cleaner in case that you not only have to hide a div.